# Classify text based on location/time from an establishing mention

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining, text-classification, information-extraction

Given a longer English text (> a few paragraphs), is there a rule-based NLP approach to classifying a set of text to be occurring at a place or time, from an establishing phrase? For example:

> Alice went to London. She met Bob at his hotel, and they went out to
>   dinner. They discussed old times and made a new friend, Cassandra.
>   Over the next week, ...
>
> [more paragraphs of activity, implicitly in London]
>
> Alice then left London and went back to Madrid. She...

As readers, we can say that Alice, Bob, and Cassandra all were in London and performed various actions there. But I can't find how to do automate this, how to match NLP techniques that I have read about with this more specific task.

Are there current tools or research that deal with this problem? I am interested in unstructured, likely narrative, text. Even a name for what this is would be helpful, something more specific than "text mining" or "text classification".

I understand that there will not be 100% accuracy with a rule-based approach. I also understand a sufficiently trained algorithm would perform this task better, but I am interested in something quick and dirty right now. Are there out-of-the-box tools that do similar work, rule-based or trained? (I am enjoying StanfordNLP, and the OpenIE module is pretty good, but doesn't quite get to this specificity, afaik.)

Comment: You can do Named Entity Recognition (NER) and then look for place names. If you assume that each mention of a place name is the location of the current and subsequent actions, then you have a straight-forward approach. Of course, this assumption is probably too optimistic for most real texts...

Comment: Definitely can use NER to retrieve places & times. And StanfordNLP can even normalize times so that they're absolute times. Pretty spiffy. But I agree it's too optimistic; assuming actions during and after the mention occur there/then means at least that you'll catch too much, particularly off-hand mentions of places, or brief mentions to say what someone else is doing.

Comment: I can get a bit further by retrieving the context/verb of the place ("went to PLACE" as opposed to "did not like PLACE as much" or "wondered how things were going in PLACE"). But I'm not sure how far I can go with that.

Comment: There are tools for explicit mentions of time (e.g. this https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/temporal-normalizer ) but not this implicit mentions.

Comment: I haven't seen that library before, looks pretty fully-featured. If the timex normalization is anything like Stanford's, sounds great! I was pretty surprised at how smooth that can be, particularly combined with coreference. I'll keep an eye on CogComp.